# How to use ccextractor in a django website to extract subtitles in windows

Tags: django, deployment, visual-web-developer, extractor, video-subtitles

I am unable to make ccextractor work with django website and if I do it how I will able to deploy the website while ccextractor work locally . I think I am missing something critical, anyone know about this or can suggest any docs .

I am expecting to extract subtiles and not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try celery in django

Refer https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

write the below code in command prompt to run celery,

```
celery -A project_name worker --loglevel=info
```